# Unable to Update Sqlite Database in Windows Phone Application

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone application, i am using Sqlite database. I am able to retrieve the data but i get a "Read Only" exception while trying to add/update any data. I am using the below code

```
public async void UpdateFavQuote(int quoteid, string option)
        {
            var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(_dbpath);

            if (option == "ADD")
            {
                await connection.ExecuteAsync("Update Quotes SET IsFav = 1 where _id =" + quoteid);
            }
            else
            {
                await connection.ExecuteAsync("Update Quotes SET IsFav = 0 where _id =" + quoteid);
            }             

        }
```

When i run the application on my emulator/device, it works fine, but once the app gets published to the store, i start getting the error. I tried using the below code but that also gives the same error

```
public void UpdateFavQuote(int quoteid, string option)
        {
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection(_dbpath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);

            if (option == "ADD")
            {
                connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {

                 connection.Execute("Update Quotes SET IsFav = 1 where _id =" + quoteid);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                   connection.Execute("Update Quotes SET IsFav = 0 where _id =" + quoteid);
                });
            }             
        }
```

This also gives the same issue once the app is published. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the database? It needs to be somewhere writable (and not in your app package for example)

Comment: @WiredPrairie It is in the following location - private static readonly string _dbpath =
            Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "QuotesDB");

Comment: You can't save back to your application package. You need to copy the database to a local folder where it can be read/write.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks.. you can answer the question and i will mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write to the application package, as it's read-only. You'll need to copy the data file into local storage so that it becomes writable. There's a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286411%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you could follow.